# JQTouch IPAD web app

Tags: jqtouch, ipad

I am developing a web app for iPad using JQTouch. It contains two split views & two single views. I am using bee desk IPad example at

http://labnote.beedesk.com/ipad-split-view-supports-on-an-jqtouchs-fork

I had two split views & single views coded in separate four files. Then I integrated all four files in to one.

When I click A button from a split view a single view should be loaded.Single view loads but it's coming as the right side of a split view.. That's the problem... Pls help

Comment: It's hard for a doctor to help if the patient doesn't tell the symptoms...

Comment: I mean I have two split views & single views coded in separate four files. When I click A button from a split view a single view should be loaded. Single view loads but it's coming as the right side of a split view.. That's the problem... Pls help

Comment: If you can put what you just said into your question (by clicking the "edit" link under your question), along with some of your own code, you should be able to attract some people to answer your question.